# Help needed to fix security issues discovered using Nikto on Ubuntu server 12.10

Tags: security, apache2, webserver

What can be done to mitigate theses security issues found by Nikto on all our Ubuntu servers version 12.10?

1. OSVDB-2799: /cgi-915/dose.pl?daily&somefile.txt&|ls|: DailyDose 1.1 is vulnerable to a directory traversal attack in the 'list' parameter.
2. OSVDB-3233: /icons/README: Apache default file found.
3. /modules.php?op=modload&name=FAQ&file=index&myfaq=yes&id_cat=1&categories=%3Cimg%20src=javascript:alert(9456);%3E&parent_id=0: Post Nuke 0.7.2.3-Phoenix is vulnerable to Cross Site Scripting (XSS).  cert.org/advisories/CA-2000-02.html.
4. This one is looking weird to me, since we do not use Web Wiz Forum script (can i assume this is just a false positive???!!!!???) :

   - OSVDB-4598: /members.asp?SF=%22;}alert('Vulnerable');function%20x(){v%20=%22: Web Wiz Forums ver. 7.01 and below is vulnerable to Cross Site Scripting (XSS).  cert.org/advisories/CA-2000-02.html.
5. OSVDB-27071: /phpimageview.php?pic=javascript:alert(8754): PHP Image View 1.0 is vulnerable to Cross Site Scripting (XSS).   cert.org/advisories/CA-2000-02.html.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

By definition,  Nikto is an Open Source (GPL) web server scanner which performs comprehensive tests against web servers for multiple items, including over 6500 potentially dangerous files/CGIs, checks for outdated versions of over 1250 servers, and version specific problems on over 270 servers. It also checks for server configuration items such as the presence of multiple index files, HTTP server options, and will attempt to identify installed web servers and software. Scan items and plugins are frequently updated and can be automatically updated.

So, your issue(s) here are in your Webserver (Apache)

But since I won't be able to give you a detailed answer as I'm not a specialist :)

here are some guidlines:

1- make sure your server is having the latest security updates and latest Apache Server version as later versions tend to fix all identified vulnerabilities.

2- Run Nikto after the update and check if some/all identified issues have been resolved

3- Check this link for details on Cross Site Scripting for all related detections http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting

4- for issue #1 and #2, refer to the official Apache SecurityTips via http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/misc/security_tips.html

5- Run Nikto again and periodically every while and after.

You may find other helpful articles if you googled on **Securing Apache Server** but I prefer official documentations myself

Hope this helps you solve your issues.